# Meaning of "self-conscience"

Tags: meaning, literature

> ‘I might go out,’ said Vicki. ‘People’s parents never like me.’
>
> ‘My parents do,’ said Arthur.
>
> ‘Older parents, I meant,’ said Vicki.
>
> ‘They might wonder exactly what you’re doing here,’ said Arthur. ‘In our
> spare room.’
>
> ‘What do you think I’m doing here?’
> He bent his smiling face over his work. ‘Well – you have to live
> somewhere, don’t you.’
>
> ‘Don’t you like me living here?’
>
> He pulled the box of Derwents towards him and flipped back the lid. ‘I’m
> going through a period of **self-conscience**,’ he said. ‘I haven’t really thought
> about it?’

"conscience" mean "The moral sense of right and wrong, chiefly as it affects one's own behaviour."

Does "self-conscience" mean "thinking about ourselves carefully that if our behaviours and our acts is moral or not"

Source: *The Children's Bach* by Helen Garner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the author is having the child try to use the term, "self-consciousness", and purposely have Andrew *misuse* it as "self-conscience".  This is called a [*malapropism*](http://www.fun-with-words.com/mala_malapropisms.html) and can be a source for humor.

Richard Sheridan's play, ["The Rivals"](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/24761), makes much use of malapropisms:

Mrs. MALAPROP: ... you will promise to forget this fellow—to **illiterate** him, I say, quite from your memory.